# How to divide a number stored in a variable by a number

Tags: assembly, pic

I have a number stored in the position `30` and I want to divide it by `10`. When I try to do so it gets the value of the register it is in instead of the value stored in the position.

```
HDUTY    EQU    30

MOVLW    D'46'
MOVWF    HDUTY

MOVLW    (HDUTY / 10)
ADDLW    '0'           ; Transform value to ASCII
CALL     LCDDWR        ; Call function to display on LCD
```

What I should see on the `W` register is `4` as `46/10 ≈ 4`, but I see a `3` as of the number of the position the `HDUTY` variable is. If I change the variable to the position `50`, I see as a result a `5` instead of a `4`. How should I do a division of the number stored in a variable by a number?

Comment: Which microcontroller?

Answer (score 1):

The format of a statement in assembly looks like this:

```
OPERATION   ARGUMENT (...ARGUMENTS)
```

Assembly is the second lowest-level programming language there is. Any calculation that happens in the argument will happen at assembler time, not at run time.

Calculations that are done at run time must be specified by you, as an operation or series of operations.

Your PIC probably does not have a division opcode, so you will have to write a division procedure yourself.

Comment: Some PIC flavours do have division op codes (e.g. dsPIC)

Comment: @EBlake better? :)

Answer (score 0):

The default PIC numeric base is hexadecimal - the 10 is actually 16.  Since 46/16 ≈ 3, you get 3 after adding '0'.